# DIV inner scroll with mouse wheel doesn't trigger mouse event refresh

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, browser

I know variations of this question has been asked, but I couldn't find neither a solution nor an explanation why this happens in those questions.

Consider a parent DIV with a scroll bar. And in that div a list of other divs that trigger on mouseover event. If I use the mouse
scrollwheel to scroll the parent div, the mouseover events don't trigger for the children, but the moment I physically move the mouse it refreshes and recalculated the coordinates and recaptures the mouseover events.

I've tried triggering the mousemove event from code - from document to specific element and nothing changes, I can't simulate the physical mouse move coordinate refresh behavior.

***What does the physical mouse move trigger in browser so that i recalculated coordinates inside the parent DIV ? Can I call that refresh from code?***

*Take the code below, as you can see scrolling with the wheel doesn't trigger hover, but the moment you move the mouse even a little the event refreshes.*

```js
jQuery(document).ready(()=>{
let p = jQuery('.parent_div');
var c;
for(let i=0;i<20;i++)
{
  c = Math.floor(Math.random()*16777215).toString(16);
  p.append('<div class="child_div" style="background-color:#'+c+'"></div>') 
}
});
```

```css
.parent_div
{
height: 100px;
overflow-y:scroll;
background-color:red;
}

.extra_parent_div
{
padding:50px;
}

.child_div
{
  height:40px;
  width:100%;
  cursor:pointer;
}

.child_div:hover
{
  background-color:white !important;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="extra_parent_div">
<div class="parent_div">
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: As far as I know, this is done for performance reasons. And not a thing you have any direct influence on.

Comment: @CBroe interesting. But is there a workaround to trigger the recalculation event?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One of the possible solutions, you can highlight '.child_div' using [.elementFromPoint()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/elementFromPoint) given `.scrollTop()` and value `clientY` previous event `mousemove`  .
Sometingh like this:

```js
if( $('.parent_div').length ) {
  for(let i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
    const color = Math.floor( Math.random()*16777215 ).toString(16);
    $('.parent_div').append(`<div class="child_div" style="background-color:#${color}"></div>`) 
  }

  let x = 0;
  let y = 0;

  $('.parent_div').on('scroll', function() {
    highlight($(this));
  })

  $(window).on('scroll', function(event) {
    highlight($(this));
  })

  $(window).on('mousemove', function(event) {
    x = event.clientX;
    y = event.clientY;
  })

  function highlight(target) {
    $('.child_div').removeClass('active');
    const yPoint = y + target.scrollTop();
    const elFromPoint = document.elementFromPoint(x, y);
    $(elFromPoint).addClass('active');
  }

  $(document).on('mouseenter', '.child_div', function() {
    $('.child_div').removeClass('active');
    $(this).addClass('active');
  })

  $(document).on('mouseleave', '.child_div', function() {
    $('.child_div').removeClass('active');
  })
}
```

```css
.parent_div {
  height: 400px;
  overflow-y: scroll;
  background-color: red;
}

.extra_parent_div {
  padding: 50px;
}

.child_div {
  height: 40px;
  width: 100%;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.child_div.active {
  background-color: white !important;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="parent_div"></div>
```